# ngIf is of no value to the Angular Heroes tutorial

Tags: angular

> Wrap the HTML hero detail content of the template with a `<div>`. Then add the ngIf built-in directive and set it to the selectedHero property of the component.

```
<div *ngIf="selectedHero">
  <h2>{{selectedHero.name}} details!</h2>
  <div><label>id: </label>{{selectedHero.id}}</div>
  <div>
  <label>name: </label>
  <input [(ngModel)]="selectedHero.name" placeholder="name"/>
</div>
```

> The app no longer fails and the list of names displays again in the browser.

The fact is that the app never fails without the ngIf directive. In order to test for that, I emptied the input form which in turn empties the bound listed item, but nothing strange happens regardless if ngIf included or not.

Any interpretation?

Comment: Are you sure there are no errors in the console? Because `selectedHero.name` should fail if `selectedHero` is undefined or null.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan zero errors

Comment: Then I guess it's a bug in the tutorial. You should probably tell the Angular team...

Comment: How do you have `selectedHero` declared in the component?

Answer (score 1):

The demo seems to fail for me using [this example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NgVNmy), the template is causing errors because the model is undefined.

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`

The ngIf directive prevents these errors by omitting the element if the model is not available.

Comment: Failed for me as well with this [DEMO on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/AaFcdmNFyyslCNYcqZcG?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

The key is in this point as explained in the [tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt2) :

> So replace the hero property with this ***simple*** selectedHero property

However, using nglf is not the only solution since initializing the selected property even with null values is enough to prevent related errors, which makes the ngif directive appears useless:

```
export class AppComponent {
  selectedHero: Hero = {
  id: null,
  name: null
 };
}
```